# CodeIgniter SQL Building

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a "send my password" type functionality and either my sql is bad or my codeigniter is bad. The form validates just fine and the function in the model gets called but nothing comes back out. I have to check two tables for the submitted email address because we separated user and admin accounts into two tables.

Controller Code:

```
 public function send() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div><br />');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        // Check For A Matching Email
        $this->load->model('signin_model');
        if ($this->signin_model('email_verify')) {

            // There Was A Match
            echo "THERE WAS A MATCH";
        } else {

            // No Match
            echo "NO MATCH";
        }

    } else {

        // Form Did Not Validate
        $this->load->view('signin/forgot');
    }
}
```

Model Code:

```
public function email_verify() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin, staff WHERE staff_email = ? OR admin_email = ?";
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $email, $email);

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

SELECT * FROM admin, staff WHERE staff_email = 'dsfsdf@test.com' OR admin_email =
```

**UPDATE**: The fixed query I'm now using is:

```
$sql = "SELECT admin_id, first_name FROM admin WHERE admin_email = ? UNION SELECT staff_id, first_name FROM staff WHERE staff_email = ?";
```

Comment: Is there any link between the `admin` and `staff` tables?  If there is, you need to add that to your `WHERE`.  If not, you need to either use 2 queries or a `UNION`.

Comment: There is no link between them. I'll look into the UNION option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->signin_model` is not a function.  It's an object.  To call a model function, you call the function as a property of the object:

```
$this->signin_model->email_verify()
```

**EDIT**: The 2nd parameter to `$this->db->query` should be an array.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($email, $email));
```

**EDIT 2**: If there is no link between the 2 tables, then a `JOIN` will not help you.  You can try a `UNION` instead.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE staff_email = ? ".
    "UNION ALL SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_email = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks. Feel pretty dumb about missing that. I now get a SQL error though that I think relates to the admin_email not being a field in the staff table. Do I need to break this into two queries or is there a better way to form this one query?

Comment: What's the SQL error?  You should be able to do it on one query.

Comment: The 2nd parameter to `$this->db->query` should be an array.

Comment: Thanks. I got the join to work. I edited the initial question to the working code. I had to specify what to pull since the two tables have a different number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($email, $email));
```

Try that. Should fix the SQL error

Comment: That fixed the error but now both valid and invalid emails are showing up no match.